# JavaScript from custom module not detected

Tags: 8, javascript

I have created a custom module, which is working. Except the JavaScript, which is not being detected. I have been following the description at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview and I have checked other modules.

What have I done to implement JavaScript? I have created a file with the following JavaScript content (location: MODULE-ROOT/js/info.js):

```
/**
 * @file
 * Info behaviors on node edit form.
 */

(function ($, window) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.nodeEditForm = {
    attach: function () {
      console.log('Hi there!');
    }
  };

})(jQuery, window);
```

Then I have added the following content into my MODULE-NAME.libraries.yml file:

```
nodeEditForm:
  version: 'VERSION'
  js:
    js/info.js: {}
```

I expect to see "Hi there!" in my webdeveloper tools inside Google Chrome browser, after I flush the entire Drupal 8 and browser cache. I do not get any output there.

Is it a "must" to attach the JavaScript to any existing behavior? If so: how can I learn which behavior is tied to an node edit form?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: But did you load the library in code anywhere? It must be attached to be included in the page. In this example it sounds like you'd want to do a hook_form_alter, and attach your library ex: `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/nodeEditForm';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Drupal uses a high-level principle: assets (CSS or JS) are still only
>   loaded if you tell Drupal it should load them. Drupal does not load
>   all assets (CSS/JS) on all pages, because this is bad for front-end
>   performance.

You need to inform Drupal to attach your library to the page.

In your case, you can use `hook_form_alter` and check the `$form_id` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` for a single case and add this:

`$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/nodeEditForm';`

Then clear the cache. Search the `core` folder for `$form['#attached']` for more examples. You should then see your js file listed in the source of the page as well as console log output.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there also an "object oriented" way to add the library from a controller or service? I have not found anything about that in the Drupal.org documentation at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module